# Can I install a ROM made for a different device? Samsung Beta

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, 7.0-nougat, android-beta-program

I have samsung galaxy s6.
Can I İnstall the beta version of nougat made for galaxy s7 to s6

Comment: Can you place star shaped piece in rectangle shaped hole?

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје No but you can fit a square shaped piece into a rectangle shaped hole.

Answer (score 0):

No.

However, I would suggest using [CyanogenMod](https://download.cyanogenmod.org) if you want to get to the latest version of Android when your phone will be no longer supported by the manufacturer.

Unfortunately, as of right now, even CyanogenMod doesn't support Samsung Galaxy S6.

Perks of having a Samsung, hehe.

People, please remember : There are no stupid question.